# Event on click only when user sign up successful ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, code-snippets

I have an event snippet for log sign-ups in my ruby on rails project. When a user creates an account (click on sign up) it will load the javascript with the snippet, but I want to load the javascript only when the user makes the account successful

Script:

```
<script>
 function googleAnalytics() {
   console.log("google analytics snippet loaded");
 }
</script>
```

html.erb file:

```
<%= button_tag f.submit t('sign_up'), type: 'button', onclick: 'googleAnalytics()', class: 'btn w-full' %>
```

Comment: You will have to move it off the button then and perform the actions after you have verified the successful sign up.

Comment: If you request HTML you cannot action anything in console (unless you redirect to a specific page where JS triggers a console.log). If you require JSON or JS (through UJS gem or UJS as a node-module) then you can do that in the function that make the request to the back end such as AJAX or Fetch.